# How to stop auto changing http to https in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I insert some content into the database using a tiny editor but the front-end if I checked it showing HTTPS format but I saved it like HTTP. If HTTPS means that like is not working. Please give a solution to stop changing the HTTP to HTTPS.

http://ebooks.edocumentonline.com/gear_for_life/winter_jackets/  - original link

But Now changing to this link https://ebooks.edocumentonline.com/gear_for_life/winter_jackets/

My htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    
</IfModule>

 # 404 Redirect
 ErrorDocument 404 https://unigear.com.au


# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php5_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 6000
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 1024M
   php_value post_max_size 64M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
   php_flag asp_tags Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 6000
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 1024M
   php_value post_max_size 64M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
   php_flag asp_tags Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: is this external link or you hosted this ?

Comment: Yes, this is not my one. third party link

Comment: then run a query to find and replace

Comment: database it's stored like http://ebooks.edocumentonline.com/gear_for_life/winter_jackets/

but frontend it's showing as https

Comment: please share your code of .htaccess file

Comment: I attached my htaccess file